# How can I create an interface for a set of classes with almost identical functionality but with different parameters and return types?

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, polymorphism

I have a series of classes that do almost the same thing. Here's what 2 of the prospective child classes look like:

```
class ItemWriter
{
    private List<Item> items;

    public ItemWriter(List<Item> items)
    {
        this.items= items;
    }

    public List<Item> Write()
    {
        using (var ctx = new DatabaseEntities())
        {
            using(var trx = ctx.Database.BeginTransaction())
            {
                ctx.Item.AddRange(items);
                rowsAdded = ctx.SaveChanges();
                trx.Commit();
            }
        }
        return items;
    }
}
```

And another...

```
class ItemShelfWriter
{
    private List<ItemShelf> itemShelfs;

    public ItemShelfWriter(List<ItemShelf> itemShelfs)
    {
        this.itemShelfs= itemShelfs;
    }

    public List<ItemShelf> Write()
    {
        using (var ctx = new DatabaseEntities())
        {
            using(var trx = ctx.Database.BeginTransaction())
            {
                ctx.TtemShelf.AddRange(itemShelfs);
                ctx.SaveChanges();
                trx.Commit();
            }
        }
        return itemShelfs;
    }
}
```

You can see that both classes do almost the same thing - only they write to different tables and the `Write()` methods have different return types.

I'd like to have an interface / abstract class `IWriter.cs` that forces every child class to have a Write() method returning a type and a constructor accepting a List. If I could remove some of the code duplication in Write() that would be good.

However, the issue is that each class takes and returns different objects and writes to a different database table. Is there any way I can achieve / improve this? I have a vague understanding that it's probably generics that need to be used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That sounds like a good case for [generics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/):

Interface:

```
public interface IWriter<T>
{
    List<T> Write();
}
```

If you can remove code duplicates depends on what your real classes actually do in detail. From the code you've shown you could do this:

```
class Writer<T> : IWriter<T>
{
    private List<T> items;

    public Writer(List<T> items)
    {
        this.items= items;
    }

    public List<T> Write()
    {
        using (var ctx = new DatabaseEntities())
        {
            using(var trx = ctx.Database.BeginTransaction())
            {
                ctx.Item.AddRange(items);
                rowsAdded = ctx.SaveChanges(); // what is rowsAdded??
                trx.Commit();
            }
        }
        return items;
    }
}
```

You did not declare `rowsAdded`, so I don't know what to do with this.

You can now instantiate this class like:

```
var itemWriter = new Writer<Item>(items);
var itemShelfWriter = new Writer<ItemShelf>(itemShelfs);
```

Comment: based off the context, rowsAdded appears to be an int. OP should clarify :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer René and apologies for my (very) slow response. This looks good but I am unsure how to handle the implementation of the public List<T> Write() method. I can use generics to pass different objects into the Write() method, but the Write() method calls a different table for each class and I am wondering if we could further reduce code duplication here? In your code you are updating the ctx.Item table each time, but each child of the IWriter<T> interface will write to a different table. This would effectively remove the need for inheritance altogether.